# KeyError while key is present in CSV file

Tags: python, file

I have problem that I get `KeyError: 'District'`  but I have column `District` in my file [here is it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7rgB.png)

Code:

```
# Create the CSV file: csvfile
csvfile = open('crime_sampler.csv', 'r')

# Create a dictionary that defaults to a list: crimes_by_district
crimes_by_district = defaultdict(list)

# Loop over a DictReader of the CSV file
for row in csv.DictReader('crime_sampler.csv'):
    # Pop the district from each row: district
    district = row.pop('District')
    # Append the rest of the data to the list for proper district in crimes_by_district
    crimes_by_district[district].append(row)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_608/747227460.py in <cell line: 8>()
      8 for row in csv.DictReader('crime_sampler.csv'):
      9     # Pop the district from each row: district
---> 10     district = row.pop('District')
     11     # Append the rest of the data to the list for proper district in crimes_by_district
     12     crimes_by_district[district].append(row)
KeyError: 'District'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error and include sample data as text and not as an image.

Comment: I can't include sample data it's in file and i can't format it to display normally here

Comment: Change "district = row.pop('District')" to "district = row['District']"

Comment: Use `for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):` instead of what you have.

Comment: For future reference, CSV files are text files, so you can open them in any text editor and copy lines from them and then paste those into your question. To get the to look right, format them as though they were code. (i.e. bracket the line pasted with triple backtick characters like this: \`\`\` ).

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html, I believe you should
change your parameter to `csv.DictReader()`:

```
    # Create the CSV file: csvfile
    csvfile = open('crime_sampler.csv', 'r')

    # Create a dictionary that defaults to a list: crimes_by_district
    crimes_by_district = defaultdict(list)

    # Loop over a DictReader of the CSV file
    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile):
        # Pop the district from each row: district
        district = row.pop('District')
        # Append the rest of the data to the list for proper district in crimes_by_district
        crimes_by_district[district].append(row)
```